# Added elements can't be used each method with on event

Tags: jquery, each

I can reach to added inputs like this:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" />'),
    jsInputAppendDiv = $("div");

var added = input.appendTo(jsInputAppendDiv);
added.on("keyup", function() { 
    // keyup function
})
```

But I wonder how we can reach to added elements to use these with each method?
I need something like this :

```
added.on("each", function() { 
    // each function
})
```

I tried all ways but I didnt achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each()` function,

```
jsInputAppendDiv.find('input[type=text]').each(function() { 
    // each function
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DVrNB/)